# FrameLog context saves changes but doesn't log changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, framelog

I've been trying to implement [FrameLog](https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/frame-log/wiki/Home) by Martin Eden. It looks like a perfect match to some requirements I considered coding myself, but realised extensibility would be limited and it would take a long time.

So I implemented the Save context method in my DbContext, using a new method called `Save(string username)` to call `Logger.SaveChanges(username, SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);`

While this saves my objects to the database, I get no change log. Does anyone have any experience with this that can lend a hand?

Here's my classes:
OppsContext.cs

```
    public OppsContext()
        : base("Name=OppsContext")
    {
        Logger = new FrameLogModule<ChangeSet, string>(new ChangeSetFactory(), FrameLogContext);
    }
    #region logging
    public DbSet<ChangeSet> ChangeSets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ObjectChange> ObjectChanges { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PropertyChange> PropertyChanges { get; set; }

    public readonly FrameLogModule<ChangeSet, string> Logger;
    public IFrameLogContext<ChangeSet, string> FrameLogContext
    {
        get { return new OppsContextAdapter(this); }
    }
    public HistoryExplorer<ChangeSet, string> HistoryExplorer
    {
        get { return new HistoryExplorer<ChangeSet, string>(FrameLogContext); }
    }

    public void Save(string author)
    {
        try
        {

            Logger.SaveChanges(author, SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

OppsContextAdapter.cs

```
        public class OppsContextAdapter : DbContextAdapter<ChangeSet, string>
{
    private OppsContext context;

    public OppsContextAdapter(OppsContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override IQueryable<IChangeSet<string>> ChangeSets
    {
        get { return context.ChangeSets; }
    }
    public override IQueryable<IObjectChange<string>> ObjectChanges
    {
        get { return context.ObjectChanges; }
    }
    public override IQueryable<IPropertyChange<string>> PropertyChanges
    {
        get { return context.PropertyChanges; }
    }
    public override void AddChangeSet(ChangeSet changeSet)
    {
        context.ChangeSets.Add(changeSet);
    }

    public override Type UnderlyingContextType
    {
        get { return typeof(OppsContext); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tis a shame I couldn't create the tag FrameLog

Comment: Have started debugging through FrameLog source, seems its comparing two value pair and deciding nothing has changed (both old and new value show new value). Not sure What I'm missing here.

Comment: That last comment led me to believe it wasn't FrameLog related, in case someone has this problem outside of this library. See answer below, as FrameLog utilizes ObjectStateEntry's [ObjectStateEntry.OriginalValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.originalvalues.aspx) and [ObjectStateEntry.CurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.currentvalues.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, found out it was my own fault. For anyone that's come here with a similar issue;

Check you're loading the object from the database before applying the new values to it. This context is the one that will need to have the original values loaded, not the post data or new object you created from it (should be an Entity).

Comment: I've been out of the loop for a while - sorry not to be of help sooner. Yes, Entity Framework will only track changes to an object while it is attached to a database context, and FrameLog asks EF for change information to log.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you solved it? See also https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/framelog/issue/45/